# Unable to delete all 'Users' from CloudKit Dashboard

Tags: ios, dashboard, cloudkit

I'm trying to clear my CloudKit dashboard of 'Users' I can't seem to manually delete them so I go into Deployment then Reset Development Environment. It still shows records exist under Users. Is there some other method to clear these?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I tried deleting a record directly in the CloudKit dashboard, but it gave me an error.

Answer (score -1):

The users records are a reflection of each user that is using your app. Why do you want to delete these records?

Comment: to test allow/disallow access to user name and email. it seems to be working now maybe i wasn't waiting long enough before.

Comment: It is ok to submit your opinion, but please try to avoid submitting it as an answer unless it also contains a solution.